# Windows 8.1 With Bing and Sysprep

Tags: sysprep, windows-8.1

I've just started looking at sysprep as an option to bypass user account creation when setting up machines for my customers, so that they can go through the OOBE themselves and still have all Windows Updates and other necessary software installed and ready to go.

It seems like Windows 8.1 With Bing is causing compatibility issues with sysprep, at least on the HP Stream tablets. Ctrl+Shift+F3 reboots the machine, it logs into the local Administrator account, and then immediately errors with the following:

> Windows could not complete the installation. To install Windows on
>   this computer, restart the installation.

I was able to get out of this eternal boot loop with Shift+F10 to get to a command prompt, run OOBE, and create a local user account. Is there any way around this so that we can use sysprep to set up machines without going through OOBE first?

Comment: I'm having the same issue myself, not sure why this would go to super-user for enterprise configs...????

Comment: I wonder if the stream is wimbooting and I wonder if you have to monkey with a custom.Wim. I'm digging into this more tomorrow as I need to deploy a few hundred of these ASAP

Comment: The Stream is, in fact, wimbooting due to having only 32GB internal storage. Did you find out anything about this?

Answer (score -1):

I would definitely suggest using a virtual machine to create your custom image, rather than a specific device. There are a number of components that could interfere with Audit Mode on a physical device complete with software and drivers.

Even further down that road, I would recommend using the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/windows/dn475741) and an image file that is as simple as possible, such as containing no software or rivers. MDT can manage drivers and software separate from the image and apply them during the deployment process. This also allows the deployment technology to be much more granular. Compare the process of using a standard image, then installing or removing software on each individual computer to create the user-ready experience, with using a universal image that can be customized at time of deployment simply by picking between options for task sequence and applications desired.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MDT can't create compressed wims